# Unable to set element proprieties passed as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code (Read the comments and the code):

```
<!-- Panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default" num="1">
<!-- There was some boring stuffs -->
<div style='float: right;'>
    <!-- Three buttons: hearth, tic and cross -->
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;" act="1"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;" act="3"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 5px;" act="0"></span>
</div>
<!-- Other boring stuffs -->
<script>
$('.glyphicon').click(function(){
    //Panel father of the button clicked
    panel = $(this).closest('div.panel');
    //Action: 1 like, 2 dislike, 3 signal, 0 accept
    act = $(this).attr('act');
    //Send request to the file that change it in the database. Ignore this until the change() function call
    $.post(
        'action.php',
        {id : panel.attr('num'), act : act},
        function(data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                //If the request is correct change DOM elements
                //First is the father panel, second the button clicked (this is the problematic argument), and the action (1, 2, 3, 0)
                change(panel, $(this), act);
            } else {
                alert('Error occurred...Please try again!');
            }
        }
    );
});
//Change DOM elements
function change(panel, obj, act) {
    //Switch the action
    switch(parseInt(act)) {
        case 1:
            //This code is executed but those three action doesn't work. Nothing change. I think the problem is the var obj
            obj.removeClass('glyphicon-heart-empty');
            obj.addClass('glyphicon-heart');
            obj.attr('act', '2');
            break;
        case 2:
            //Same thing here, but I haven't checked this because first the code of case 1 need to work.
            obj.removeClass('glyphicon-heart');
            obj.addClass('glyphicon-heart-empty');
            obj.attr('act', '1');
            break;
        case 3:
            //The panel var works very well and those blocks works
            panel.removeClass('panel-default');
            panel.addClass('panel-warning');
            break;
        default:
            panel.removeClass('panel-warning');
            panel.addClass('panel-default');
    }
}
</script>
```

I want that when i click the hearth it fills and if i click again it return empty. The problem is when i try to set element proprities of `obj`  element that is the hearth clicked. I'm sure that the code is executed because i debugged it adding a `console.log()` in the cases 1 and 2. It doesn't return errors and the code seems to work but nothing happend and clicking again the attr `act` is the same.

Comment: Can you create a code example in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Sure @MaxZoom [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbcgans1/)

Comment: Thx Felix, I have come up with the same [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vbcgans1/1/) as Gabriel did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `$.post` success callback, `this` is no longer the element you are clicking (which is what you need to pass to `change`). You need to save a reference to said element outside the `$.post` callback, and use it as the parameter when calling change, such as:

```
$('.glyphicon').click(function(){
    var icon = $(this),
       panel = icon.closest('div.panel'),
         act = icon.attr('act');

    $.post(
        'action.php',
        {id : panel.attr('num'), act : act},
        function(data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                change(panel, icon, act);
            } else {
                alert('Error occurred...Please try again!');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code have issue inside the ajax. Means you have to define the click object before calling ajax , like below .

```
var click_obj = '';

$('.glyphicon').click(function(){


click_obj = $(this);


//Panel father of the button clicked
panel = $(this).closest('div.panel');
//Action: 1 like, 2 dislike, 3 signal, 0 accept
act = $(this).attr('act');
//Send request to the file that change it in the database. Ignore this until the change() function call
$.post(
    'action.php',
    {id : panel.attr('num'), act : act},
    function(data) {
        if (data == '1') {
            //If the request is correct change DOM elements
            //First is the father panel, second the button clicked (this is the problematic argument), and the action (1, 2, 3, 0)


            change(panel, click_obj, act);


        } else {
            alert('Error occurred...Please try again!');
        }
     }
   );
});
```